# Using lazy-init pattern properties on Apex data objects in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

More of a technical question than a philosophical, because I am mainly interested in the intelligence of the LWC cache and any performance implications.

I use the lazy-init pattern extensively in Apex, when implementing complex objects. The code usually looks something like this

```
@AuraEnabled
public List<String> Errors {
    public get {
        if (Errors == null) Errors = getErrors();
        return Errors;
    }
    private set; 
}
```

Where `Errors` is an object property and `getErrors()` is a private function that initializes the List of errors (where I know, that once initialized, the errors will never change during the life-time of the object).

Now considering client/server round trips: What happens in LWC under the hood, if I use `@wire` to import and call an apex method that retrieves a list of objects with lazy-init properties? My JavaScript / HTML **may** access said properties. Are there any unnecessary round trips where it would be faster / more efficient to simply load all Properties with the constructor?

PS: I recently started with LWC, so I'm always thankful if you point me to existing resources that already answer my question.

Comment: Adding properties in class and returning as datatype is fine. I have misread your question. Deleted my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When LWC actually calls some Apex, the AuraEnabled results are serialized to JSON, allowing it to be transported over HTTP (AJAX) to the client. That means the whole object (at least the AuraEnabled parts) is walked, during the serialization, to access all property values at that time. This means your properties will all get read (and therefore all your lazy loading private methods called as a side effect) at that point.

LWC communications do not get partial objects back and then fetch other parts later. (This is different to your application allowing partial object trees to be returned, but that's code you write to set up and return the required Apex objects.)

Comment: Thanks Phil, I realised I have misread the question

Comment: No worries. Your contributions are usually pretty good so it's OK to have a Friday moment ;)